# Is Django trying to make the same table two times?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a problem with Django quite incomprehensible.

I used `models.py` to model my database. This database runs on the production server. I want to change it, so I create a new database on the development server. The problem happens when I do `syncdb`, Django tries to create twice the same table, as you can see below:

```
python manage.py syncdb

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: inventaryApp, newPrpvApp, grappelli, debug_toolbar, registration, import_export
  Apply all migrations: sitetree, sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table u_institutions
    Creating table u_users
    Creating table o_organes
    Creating table o_degats
    Creating table o_validation
    Creating table o_m_determination
    Creating table o_stades_dvlpmt
    Creating table o_types
    Creating table precision_date
    Creating table t_categories
    Creating table t_etat_synonymie
    Creating table g_langues
    Creating table g_pays
    Creating table g_regions
    Creating table g_communes
    Creating table pays_langues
    Creating table newprpvapp_userprofile
    Creating table t_noms_verna
    Creating table langues_noms_verna
    Creating table maladies
    Creating table t_familles
    Creating table t_genres
    Creating table t_especes
    Creating table images
    Creating table esp_noms_verna
    Creating table t_infra_types
    Creating table t_infra_sp
    Creating table t_synonymes
    Creating table o_contexte
    Creating table o_interception
    Creating table o_hotes
    Creating table hotes_organes
    Creating table o_organismes_associes
    Creating table u_institutions
```

As you can see, the u_institutions table is created the first, but also at the end. And this is where the execution of the command stops to show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 239, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "u_institutions" already exists
```

I have verified that the table had not been set twice in `model.py`, and it was not. I use `Django 1.7`, and `psycopg 2.6`. Do you have an idea please? Thank you all!

**Edit**

I had already executed `makemigrations`, and everything was good. Now it indicates that no change is detected, which is probably normal.

When I try `migrate`, I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 239, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "u_institutions" already exists
```

And `migrate --fake` return :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 239, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/hugo/DEV/.virtualenvs/env_eprpv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "u_institutions" already exists
```

Comment: Still not fix. I made a new db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have already created your database schema. Please, use migration (as long as you use Django 1.7). `syncdb` is deprecated.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If you will face any errors here (like `relation "..." already exists`) run this command to mark this tables as applied:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: @DadaArno can you try to run the command `python manage.py migrate --fake  <appname>` for every single app you have? Or just clean your database before migrating.

Comment: I try `python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>` but :

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
`


My database has just been created :/

Comment: You should manually recreate your database and run `python manage.py migrate`  (with no `--fake`) when you will have empty database with no tables.